# How to declare a dynamic 2D array in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, dynamic

I'm trying to define a dynamic 2D Array in C++ using the following definition:

```
int foo(string parameter){
    const int n = parameter.length();
    int* Array = new int[n][n];
return 0;
}
```

I receive an error that array size in new expression must be constant, can't understand why because `Array` is supposed to be dynamic.

Comment: A dynamic 2D array in C++ is a `std::vector<std::vector>`. To fix your code you can `int* Array = new int[n * n];` and access the elements with `Array[row + n * col]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(someone posted a shorter version of this in the comments while I was writing it).

What you need for a 2D array allocated with `new` is this:

```
int foo(string parameter){
    const int n = parameter.length();
    int* Array = new int[n*n];
    return 0;
}
```

And then access cells with appropriate indexing.

Another solution is to use `vector`.

```
int foo(string parameter){
    const int n = parameter.length();
    vector<vector<int>> Array(n, vector<int>(n));
    return 0;
}
```